# Flutter Map Marker Rotation

Tags: android, flutter, fluttermap

I have trouble using the flutter map marker and rotating it based on the user heading. My app requires custom GPS coordinates, so I cannot use a built-in marker option. I need some way to rotate a marker in flutter_map, but so far I can't get anything to work. The documentation says to use Transform.rotate, but that is also not working. I am very new to app dev and flutter. Thank you for any help.

The documentation says to use Transform.rotate, but that is also not working. I also tried to use the location package, but I can't figure out how to use it either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.